# Scrollbar in tkinter not showing up - macos

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm learning how to do GUI in python, I am trying to make a scrollbar for my listbox but it's not showing up. I tried many different things with the same results, so to make sure that I am not doing something wrong I went to the example in [Python-Tkinter Scrollbar](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-scrollbar/) and tried to run it but the scrollbar still did not show. Can anyone help me and tell me why is it not working?

The result is shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

The code for the example is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("150x200")

w = Label(root, text ='GeeksForGeeks',
          font = "50")

w.pack()

scroll_bar = Scrollbar(root)

scroll_bar.pack( side = RIGHT,
                fill = Y )

mylist = Listbox(root,
                 yscrollcommand = scroll_bar.set )

for line in range(1, 26):
    mylist.insert(END, "Geeks " + str(line))

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )

scroll_bar.config( command = mylist.yview )

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I see the scrollbar on your screenshot, on the far right of the screen. If you shrink the window so that not all data fits, you should see the bar inside of the scrollbar appear.

Comment: It may have worked but there's not enough content to make the scrollbar appear. Try making the window smaller with `root.geometry("150x50")`.

Comment: Judging by the original size of the screenshot (1458x1334) you had in your question (i.e. before I resized it), I'm guessing that you probably have an Apple high-res Retina® display with many more pixels than is commonly available. For that reason you may encounter similar issues with code written assuming normal resolution displays — so be prepared to think different and have to adapt such code accordingly. Also see the stackexchange [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) website.

Answer (score 0):

I use to face a similar problem. It can be fixed by defining the scrollbar and packing it before packing the listbox.

Here is the final code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("150x200")

w = Label(root, text ='GeeksForGeeks',
          font = "50")

w.pack()

mylist = Listbox(root)

scroll_bar = Scrollbar(root, command=mylist.yview, orient=VERTICAL)

scroll_bar.pack( side = RIGHT,
                fill = Y )

for line in range(1, 26):
    mylist.insert(END, "Geeks " + str(line))

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )

mylist.config( yscrollcommand = scroll_bar.set )

root.mainloop()
```

Thank You!

Comment: i tried this solution but i am still facing the same issue, is the problem happening because i am using a mac?

Comment: Even without the scrollbar if the Listbox is scrollable then it's a fixable problem. If not, then I think the problem is with Listbox or mac.

Comment: what do you mean its a fixable problem?